# Request to burninate the tag "Puree"

Tags: discussion, tags

That tag is strange, while looking for a tag "purifying" that tag shows up. And I don't really know the purpose of that tag. Currently there are no questions under that tag.

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/puree/info

Comment: There are four questions tagged "puree" - http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puree?sort=newest Did you mean no one has tagged anything "purifying"?

Comment: Just a note, it's both a verb and a noun. If you put broccoli in a blender, you are pureeing the broccoli. The resulting product is broccoli puree.

Comment: Cary, one more thing if you are not aware how Meta works: The downvotes here mean "I disagree with your suggestion" (so people think the tag should stay), not "It's a bad question". To your best knowledge, the tag did not mean anything, so it was a good thing to start a discussion about it. Don't be discouraged by the downvotes, they are used differently on Meta than on main.

Comment: @rumtscho, I didn't know that! Thanks for the information! Yeah, I will not be discouraged. Thanks again Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason to remove it. Just because nobody has thought of using it doesn't mean that nobody will do so in the future. And I see no red flags with it - it is not suffering from homonym problems, or from being a meta-tag.

Is it possible that there is a language issue? `Puree` is a culinary term used for mashed vegetables, but if you have not heard it, maybe you thought that it is not a real word? I admit that it is somewhat uncommon in English.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've not heard it. I was thinking that it is a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Tags can't exist without being used on questions - but as it's been pointed out, there are actually four questions with the tag, which is more than enough to keep it out of purgatory.

Comment: Aaronut is correct in principle. There is one exception: when a question with the tag is created and later deleted. In this case, the tag continues to exist for a few months, after which it is automatically destroyed. So it's not completely impossible to find a tag without questions for it, although very rare.

Comment: @rumtscho, thanks! very informative. I really appreciate for helping me.

Comment: I think it is also the canonical name for a component in certain platings?

Comment: @rackandboneman I have never heard it used for anything which was not made from mashed vegetables or fruit. If you have examples for a different usage, I'd love to see them and educate myself.

Comment: It seems to be a standard  in all these swanky fish dishes presented on masterchef and stuff, so I assumed it was also a formal term for whatever is used to keep the fish from sliding off the plate...